# hide/show table cell based on previous cell

Tags: jquery

I would like to show/hide a table cell based on the value in the previous cell. If the previous cell has a value than show else hide. Jquery should evaluate this for every row. I now have the following code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input[name^="OS"]').hide();
    jQuery('input[name^="OF"]').on('keyup', function(){ 
        jQuery('table#form_er tr').each(function(){ 
            if(!jQuery('input[name^="OF"]').val()){
                jQuery('input[name^="OS"]').hide();}
            else {jQuery('input[name^="OS"]').show();}
        });
    });
});
```

The result now is that all the OS-cells are hiden even if OF is filled, if I fill an empty OF all the OS-cells are show and when I clear an OF-cell nothing changes. 
Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. In your case you can do it even easier: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` and then use `$` inside.

Comment: Hello Thiefmaster, I know, but I using it inside web2py and than I have to use it like this.

Comment: Can you just show or hide table cell's because it looks like you're toggling just the input fields. Also you can get to the next node using jquery's next function: http://jqapi.com/#p=next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **jQuery(this)** and **closest('tr')** to target the cells only in the current row..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input[name^="OS"]').hide();
    jQuery('input[name^="OF"]').on('keyup', function() {
        jQuery('table#form_er tr').each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).val() != '') {
                jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="OS"]').hide();
            }
            else {
                jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="OS"]').show();
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

if the cell you want to target is the next cell .. Then you can do this as well..

```
jQuery(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input[name^="OS"]').hide();
```

**EDIT**

Replace `!jQuery(this).val()` **with**  `jQuery(this).val() != ''`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sushant, but this is not working. The result is now that the OS-cells are not shown at all

Comment: Instead of !jQuery(this).val()  try this jQuery(this).val() != ''

Comment: Hi Sushanth, the result is that all the OS-cells are shown and never hide. The code is like this now:    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input[name^="OS"]').hide();
    jQuery('input[name^="OF"]').on('keyup', function() {
        jQuery('table#form_er tr').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).val() !== ''
                jQuery(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input[name^="OS"]').hide();
            }
            else {
                jQuery(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input[name^="OS"]').show();
            }
            });
        });
    });

Comment: Hi Sushanth, I am getting close. Now if the page is loaded all of OS-cells are hidden, I only want the OS-cells hidden if the OF-cell in the same row is empty. Also if I fill an empty OF-cell all the OS-cells are shown, also the ones of which the OF-cell is empty. Can you help me a little bit more?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has responded to this question. I have solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think you code is right, but may be $('input[name^="OS"]').val() is empty.

Comment: Hello Liocin, the tablerows are like this:<tr><td><input type=text name=OF/></td><td><input type=text name=OS/></td></tr><tr><td><input type=text name=OF/></td><td><input type=text name=OS/></td></tr>

Comment: yes, i konw, may be you can see Sushanth answer use $(this) to get value